# Erro executar Nancy no Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Olá tenho uma aplicação (executavel) que estou tentando rodar em uma VM Linux no Azure, ela funciona no projeto, porém ao executar com o Mono (Já instalei tudo possivel fsharp, mono-complete) e da o erro abaixo

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more details. ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: jAnalisa.Security.Modules.AuthModule ---> System.ArgumentException: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.
  at jAnalisa.Security.Modules.AuthModule..ctor (Nancy.Authentication.Token.ITokenizer tokenizer) [0x000ab] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000f7] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0010d] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.<ResolveAllInternal>b__43 (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration) [0x0000c] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00045] in <7c7d16af841f44d5a362340966c7fd69>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__34`1[TResult].MoveNext () [0x0005f] in <7c7d16af841f44d5a362340966c7fd69>:0
  at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache.BuildCache (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] modules) [0x000b0] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache..ctor (Nancy.INancyModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, Nancy.INancyContextFactory contextFactory, Nancy.Routing.IRouteSegmentExtractor routeSegmentExtractor, Nancy.Routing.IRouteDescriptionProvider routeDescriptionProvider, Nancy.Culture.ICultureService cultureService, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] routeMetadataProviders) [0x00042] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000f7] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0010d] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType) [0x00011] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] () [0x00000] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.DefaultNancyBootstrapper.GetEngineInternal () [0x00006] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1[TContainer].SafeGetNancyEngineInstance () [0x00000] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at jAnalisa.Security.Program.InitApi () [0x00070] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
  at jAnalisa.Security.Program.Main () [0x00001] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies during composition, make sure that you've registered all new dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more details. ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache ---> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: jAnalisa.Security.Modules.AuthModule ---> System.ArgumentException: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.
  at jAnalisa.Security.Modules.AuthModule..ctor (Nancy.Authentication.Token.ITokenizer tokenizer) [0x000ab] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000f7] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0010d] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.<ResolveAllInternal>b__43 (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration) [0x0000c] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00045] in <7c7d16af841f44d5a362340966c7fd69>:0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__34`1[TResult].MoveNext () [0x0005f] in <7c7d16af841f44d5a362340966c7fd69>:0
  at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache.BuildCache (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] modules) [0x000b0] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.Routing.RouteCache..ctor (Nancy.INancyModuleCatalog moduleCatalog, Nancy.INancyContextFactory contextFactory, Nancy.Routing.IRouteSegmentExtractor routeSegmentExtractor, Nancy.Routing.IRouteDescriptionProvider routeDescriptionProvider, Nancy.Culture.ICultureService cultureService, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] routeMetadataProviders) [0x00042] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000f7] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0010d] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000b2] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x000d6] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType (System.Type requestedType, System.Type implementationType, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00009] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+SingletonFactory.GetObject (System.Type requestedType, Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x0003b] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, Nancy.TinyIoc.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, Nancy.TinyIoc.ResolveOptions options) [0x00027] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType) [0x00011] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] () [0x00000] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.DefaultNancyBootstrapper.GetEngineInternal () [0x00006] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
  at Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1[TContainer].SafeGetNancyEngineInstance () [0x00000] in <63c44d6f8d7e4f339a987bf9eb94d931>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at jAnalisa.Security.Program.InitApi () [0x00070] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
  at jAnalisa.Security.Program.Main () [0x00001] in <e684f55928c143c2b620ac75291d2cec>:0
jmsoft@IronMan:~/microservices/security$
```

Comment: Não falta alguma configuração de string de conexão em algum lugar? O erro que você apresentou diz: *'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.*

Comment: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Building-Nancy-on-Mono